# After using VS 2012 to build WebKit, MiniBrowser can't run. Can't find msvcr80.dll

Tags: build, webkit, visual-studio-2012

Recently, I try to build WebKit with VS2012. That cost me a lot of time to fix the errors. After a successful build, MiniBrowser can't run normally.

Building Environment:
MSVS 2012
Windows 8 x64

I have fixed every error it alerts me, but after builded in Debug mode, MiniBrowser can't run. It just alert something below:

The program can't start because MSVCR80.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

But when I build it in release mode, MiniBrowser just run normally, why ?

Comment: Sounds odd, I thought (and please correct me if I'm wrong) `MSVCR80.dll` was a remnant from VS2005. Are there any binary modules used in your webkit that may reference old DLLs?

Comment: yes, maybe. Maybe I should check this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I have faced this problem. Check the following link, this may help you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/6d16ecce-f92b-4c53-a45b-40119c4566a6/